# When moved, the area under a UINavigationBar is no longer touchable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, touch, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationBar that is visible. When I move this element offscreen, the area underneath no longer accepts touches.

Any idea why this is happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: How exactly are you hiding the UINavigationBar?  You should be using the setNavigationBarHidden method on your instance.

Comment: i do not really want to hidden the UINavigationBar. so i do like this:
r = self.parentController.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
r = CGRectMake(0, - offsetY, r.size.width, r.size.height);
self.parentController.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = r;        
because i want hidden the navigation bar when scrolling the view up ,and show navigation bar when scrolling view down . thank you !

Answer (score 0):

When you move the `navigationBar` by setting a custom `frame` to it, do you change the `frame` of the contentView of the `UINavigationController`?

If not, the part under the `navigationBar` may be visible but is not inside the `navigationController`'s contentView, so touches on it won't be detected.

Comment: of course i also change the frame of the contentView of the UINavigationController ,but it also do not work expectly.i find this in UINavigationBar Class Reference :Customizing the Appearance of a Navigation Bar Prior to iOS v5.0, when used in conjunction with a navigation controller, there are only a handful of direct customizations you can make to the navigation bar. Specifically, it is alright to modify the barStyle, tintColor, and translucent properties, but you must never directly change UIView-level properties such as the frame, bounds, alpha, or hidden properties directly. find reason?

Comment: Well, it is not recommended by Apple, as they don't like when you try to customize things ^^ But it should work anyway… Weird…